# Как сделать меню в bootstrap -3

Tags: css, bootstrap

Есть ли возможность сделать меню bootstrap-3 на ширину экрана, а не родительского компонента?
есть необходимость организовать меню таким образом [image]
пытался реализовать таким образом

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-20 col-xs-20">
                            <li><a href="#">Главная/a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Для него </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked nav-tabs">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#home_him" data-toggle="tab">Главная</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#profile_him" data-toggle="tab">Профиль</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#messages_him" data-toggle="tab">Сообщения</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#settings_him" data-toggle="tab">Настройки</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home_him">
                                            <li><a href="#">Действие</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Другое действие</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Что-то еще</a></li>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane" id="profile_him">
                                            <li><a href="#">Действие</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Другое действие</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Что-то еще</a></li>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane" id="messages_him">
                                            <li><a href="#">Действие</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Другое действие</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Что-то еще</a></li>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane" id="settings_him">
                                            <li><a href="#">Действие</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Другое действие</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Что-то еще</a></li>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </ul>
                            </li> 
                                                       ...
                                               </ul>
                                       </div>
                                 </div>
```

из этого ни чего не вышло даже выпадающее меню не работает можно в bootstrap 3 стандартными методами сделать такое меню ?

Comment: container-fluid

Comment: Зависит от вашей текущей верстки. И от того, насколько ее можно изменить. Можно ли расположить меню вне `.container` и других подобных блоков?

Comment: @ВиталийЕмельянцев я пока тему изучаю как лучше это сделать чем верстаю так сказать спрашиваю о лучших рецептах.

Comment: @soledar10 опубликуйте ответ, вопрос открытым висит, а ответ вы уже написали в комментарии .

Comment: @ВиталийЕмельянцев кто вам сказал что я нашел ответ? То, что я нашел, мне как ответ не нравится.

Comment: лучший рецепт меню, сделать ее самому

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/72ab1jho/)

```css
.nav > li.dropdown.open {
  position: static;
}
.nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
  display: table;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu > li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-menu > li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="navbar-brand">LOGO</div>
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".btnCollapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse btnCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link 2<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link 4<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: dropdown ставится по ширине контейнера родителя

Comment: @Sergalas - добавил пример